# Unable to pass text to an HTML5 dialog box via Appium sendKeys() command

Tags: android, python, appium

I am using Python in conjunction with Appium to automate testing on an Android mobile device. I am using the Appium/Selenium webdriver and launching Chrome on the device. There is a dialog that I am targeting with a username field and I am able to find the Username textbox via XPath and even click into it to start typing. However when I use the sendKeys() command to enter text into into, it does nothing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Code (Python):

```
    try:
        self.prac_btn = self.get_ele('xpath', '//*[@id="dialogMessage"]/fieldset/input[1]')
        print "Found username"
    except:
        print "Cannot find username"

    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        self.click_ele(self.prac_btn)
    except:
        print "Cannot click on username"

    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        self.prac_btn.send_keys(self, "Username")
    except:
        print "Cannot type text"
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `self` as the first argument to `send_keys()`?  I suspect you're getting an exception calling `send_keys()` because you're passing too many arguments.

Comment: Hi John, you were spot on. I was under the impression that Python always requires 'self' as the first parameter and the method structure is as such: send_keys(self, *value). Thanks for the direction it seems to be working 100% now.

Comment: @JohnGordon : could you detail an answer out of it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by passing two arguments to `send_keys()`, which only accepts one argument.  `self` is not needed as an argument because `send_keys()` is a class instance function.  `self` is passed implicitly.

This is also a good example of why a bare `except` is dangerous. If you had caught the exception and printed it, you would have seen something like this:

```
TypeError: send_keys() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Which would have been a strong clue as to what went wrong.